# Define a range for one color using Blend

Tags: plotting, color

I use `Blend` to color my `ListDensityPlot`. 
In my code below, I use white for zero. I would like to use white between -0.6 to 0.6. How should I change  `(Blend[{{-0.6, Blue}, {0, White}, {0.6, Red}}, #] &)]`

```
 graph = ListDensityPlot[data, 
   ColorFunction -> (Blend[{{-0.6, Blue}, {0, White}, {0.6, Red}}, #] &)]
```

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/145365/use-blend-to-specify-different-colors-for-different-ranges-of-values

Comment: I checked this question. But i am not really sure, shiuld I change x_ by # in my case ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps

```
data = Table[Cos[i] Cos[j + i], {i, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/32}, {j, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/32}]; 
ListDensityPlot[data, 
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{{-1, Blue}, {-0.6, White}, {0.6, White}, {1, Red}}, #] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{-.6, .6}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it is a good alternative way, I didn't thought about to add one `{-0.6, White}` in my function `(Blend[{{-0.6, Blue}, {0, White}, {0.6, Red}}, #] &)]`